# How to create multiselect dropdown option in excel using c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel

I am unable to create multiselect dropdown in excel using c#.
I am able to create dropdown but I want to create multiselect option also.

Comment: What type of drop down are you trying to create?  In-cell, Active X, Forms?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.